# Mapping list of objects which has a "id" as a property with a list of ids. Lets say the datatype is integer

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, java-8, logic

Lets say I have an pojo object

```
Obj--> {"id":1, "name":"demo"}
```

I have two `ArrayList.
One list of those objects and another a list of integers. Now, what is the best way to code so that I can map list of integers with the list of objects.

what I need is a Map having `id` as a key and all those objects with similar ids as a list in that map.

For example:

```
Obj1 with id 1
Obj2 with id 1
Obj3 with id 2
Obj4 with id 2
```

The map will have

```
for key --> id:1  Value Obj1 and Obj2
for key --> id:2 Value Obj3 and Obj4
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look into `Collectors.groupingBy`.  This has been answered tons of times on SO already.

Comment: This looks like a `Map<Integer, List<Object>>`, i recommend using Guava `Multimap` for that.

Comment: `Collectors.gropingBy()`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the need of two array lists, you can group by the identifier of each pojo to collect them into a `Map<Integer, List<Pojo>>` where each identifier can map to many pojos having the same identifier.

`pojos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pojo::getId))`